# Pandas UserWarning when using df.loc based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I've below dataframe where I want to change values based on condition

```
    name    checker data
0  user1  user122AB   10
1  user2  user132AB   12
2  user3  user346AB   14
3  user4  user108AB   16
4  user5  user122CD   10
5  user6  user132CD   12
6  user7  user346CD   14
7  user8  user108CD   16
```

Expected output:

```
    name    checker data
0  user1  user122AB   10
1  user2  user132AB   12
2  user3  user346AB   14
3  user4  user108AB   16
4  user5  user122CD  900
5  user6  user132CD  900
6  user7  user346CD  900
7  user8  user108CD  900
```

I'm using below code for same.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([["user1", "user122AB", "10"], ["user2", "user132AB", "12"], ["user3", "user346AB", "14"], ["user4", "user108AB", "16"], ["user5", "user122CD", "10"], ["user6", "user132CD", "12"], ["user7", "user346CD", "14"], ["user8", "user108CD", "16"]], columns=["name", "checker", "data"])
df.loc[df.checker.str.contains("\d+\w*(CD)$"), "data"] = "900"
print(df)
```

It is doing the exact thing that I want but throwing below warning along with output.

```
UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
```

Please help if I'm doing something wrong or please share any better way to achieve this.

Comment: This will not work if there is any entry like "userABCD" in checker field. I have to use regex on this to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this warning because of the parenthesis. You are searching for matching patterns, to be returned. I think this is unnecessary.
`pandas` (1.0.3) is coded to send a warning is the regex match one ore more parenthesis patterns (`if regex.groups > 0: warnings.warn(...)`).

The line below is then working without warning:

```py
df.loc[df.checker.str.contains("\d+\w*CD$"), "data"] = "900"
```